Maven project showing red cross
why this red cross error showing on my project in Eclipse(IDE), even there is no error showing inside the project, and project is running smoothly.
enter image description here
At first, it is showing error in jsp page, so i do some changes in build path configuration and my project start working.
Now what to do to remove this error?

Check the Problems view to get more details about it. You can also try updating your project by going to Maven > Update Project.

You should name the IDE (eclipse) which the error is showing and provide the exact error from the problems view to get a better answer to your problem
